# Jenkins ../ java.io.FileNotFoundException

Tags: java, jenkins, wsdl

Console error jenkins

error search directory jenkins

> java.io.FileNotFoundException:
>   /opt/puntal-sonar/jenkins/jobs/RProf/workspace/rprof-app-web/rprof-ws-respuesta-sns/src/main/resources/schemas/XSD/tipo_reps_biztalk.xsd (No such file or directory)

[image: directory structure]

callbackprofesional.wsdl

```
  <wsdl:types>      
    <xsd:schema targetNamespace="http://www.msssi.es/reps/xsd/CallBackProfesionalCA">
       <xsd:import namespace="http://www.msssi.es/reps/xsd/tipos_reps"  schemaLocation="../XSD/tipos_reps.xsd"/>
       <xsd:import namespace="http://www.msssi.es/reps/xsd/tipos_reps_respuesta" schemaLocation="../XSD/tipos_reps_respuesta.xsd" />            
       <xsd:import namespace="http://www.sergas.es/rprof/respuestabiztalk"  schemaLocation="../XSD/tipo_reps_biztalk.xsd"/>
```

Solutions?

Comment: Stack overflow post.
Use very little words. Must not press downvote. Add more info.

Comment: The obvious question is: does that file exist?

Comment: Please look at the picture ... this catching the wrong route does not go to the previous directory ...

Comment: obviously the file is in the folder... src/main/resources/XSD not in .../resources/schemas... this does not work "../" in the wsdl

Comment: src->main->XSD its OK /// src->main->resources->XSD Its why Fail not find the correct route??

Comment: Fully expand the XSD directory and show a picture of its contents. Your picture is irrelevant to your question..

Answer (score 0):

Isn't the `.xsd` resolved relative to `callbackprofesional.wsdl`? So that should point to `../../XSD/tipos_reps.xsd`?